# How to get input via a popup and place text in a variable via javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a button on my page.  When clicked a popup box should appear allowing the user to enter text.  When OK/Submit is pressed, my jscript will then perform some functions using that inputted data.  Very straightforward, but I just can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

in it's simplest form, you could use **prompt(question, default)**:
(taken from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt)

```
function myFunction(){
    var x;
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");
    if (name!=null){
       x="Hello " + name + "! How are you today?";
      alert(x);
   }
}
```

anything else would require lots of javascript & CSS to create layers with buttons and click events on those buttons

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly, but I was wondering if its possible to make this box bigger, like a squarish text input box?

Comment: nope, it's a browser specific window. Like i said, you'll have to use javascript/CSS to create boxes like that. there's probably libraries available to use for this, like jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code inside your `head` tags between `script` tags

**HTML**

```
<button id="button">Get Text</button>​
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var el=document.getElementById('button');
    el.onclick=function(){
        var my_text=prompt('Enter text here');
        if(my_text) alert(my_text); // for example I've made an alert
    }
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNsJf/)